# How to change the iOS compatibility to iOS 13 in App Store

Tags: flutter, xcode, app-store

MyFP minimum version required is incorrectly displayed on the app store.

Shows v13 in app details section(Correct Version).
Shows v12 in Information section.

[image: Screenshot of the App]

[image: screenshot of the XCODE 1]

[image: screenshot of the XCODE 2]

[image: POD file]

Comment: I suggest you you check . xcodeproj directly, and look for lines with: `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`